# Adding a measure to a powerbi matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax

I built a matrix with a measure in values which sums a column(cost of employees) by employee and type of cost. I need to add to the matrix a column with the sum of hours worked, unfiltered, and a column with the hourly cost, calculated like the sum of costs divide by the hours.
Thanks.

Comment: If you can give sample data and expected output. That will help alot